# Grunt-manifest: Put to a subdirectory the source paths

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, manifest

I create an offline-working site, and I use the [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to run the tasks. I build the static site from my local-stored, then run the manifest for these files, and copy them to a server. But I have to store them in a subdirectory on the server. Somehow the list in the manifest file should have a prefix with the name of this subdirectory.

I use this config in the `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    manifest: {
        generate: {
            options: {
                basePath: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/',
                network: ['*'],
                preferOnline: false,
                verbose: false,
                timestamp: true
            },
            src: [
                'fonts/*',
                'images/*',
                'scripts/*.js',
                'styles/*.css'
            ],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/manifest.appcache'
        }
    }
});
```

(I use the [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to store the directory value, but it isn't important.)

The result is:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Time: Wed Jul 02 2014 18:26:02 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)

CACHE:
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
images/test.png
images/test2.png
scripts/05dd5665.scripts.js
.
.
.

NETWORK:
*
```

But I would need it like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Time: Wed Jul 02 2014 18:26:02 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)

CACHE:
subDir/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
subDir/images/test.png
subDir/images/test2.png
subDir/scripts/05dd5665.scripts.js
.
.
.

NETWORK:
*
```

Any hints? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try specifing the `basePath` to something like '.' and then you could append `<%= yeoman.dist %>/` to each entry inside `src`

```
grunt.initConfig({
    manifest: {
        generate: {
            options: {
                basePath: '.',
                network: ['*'],
                preferOnline: false,
                verbose: false,
                timestamp: true
            },
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/*',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/*',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/*.css'
            ],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/manifest.appcache'
        }
    },
    replace :{
            key: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
});
```

This will append the value of `<%= yeoman.dist %>` in front of each entry in the `CACHE` section. You could use a search and replace tool (i.e. `sed`) to replace the value of `<%= yeoman.dist %>` with your desired subdir. A grunt task to do this would look like

```
var String = require('string'); // pull this dependency with npm install string --save-dev
grunt.registerMultiTask('replace', 'A task to search and replace', function () {
    var bufferJs = grunt.file.read(this.data+'/manifest.appcache');
    var mainManifest = String(bufferJs.toString());
    mainManifest = mainManifest.replaceAll(this.data, 'mySubdir');
    grunt.file.write(this.data+'/manifest.appcache', mainManifest);
});
```

In order to create the manifest file and then do the search and replace operation, you can create a separate grunt task that invokes both sub-tasks. The following task will run `manifest` first, then `replace`.

```
grunt.registerTask('create_manifest', ['manifest', 'replace:key']);
```

Finally, to run the composite task, run the following from command line

```
grunt create_manifest
```

Comment: And where or when should I call this tool? Sorry for the question, I'm new in the grunt...

Comment: You can use the `replace` task instead of the `sed` tool. `sed` is a linux shell command. You could invoke shell commands from your grunt script, using [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell), but I think the best way forward is just a custom grunt task. Using `sed` means that you can only build in linux, whereas a grunt task would work everywhere.

Comment: I use Windows, and it should run in anybody's environment... I try the grunt-shell.

Comment: I editted my answer to illustrate how to run a custom grunt task `create_manifest` which will do both the manifest creation and the replace without using any shell or command line tools. This should work across all platforms. Note you need the dependency `String`. You can pull it `npm install string --save-dev`

Comment: It's will be okay, but I have an error: 
`Warning: Unable to read "<%= yeoman.dist %>/manifest.appcache" file (Error code: ENOENT). Used --force, continuing.`
I can write this file, but not to read... And the file is exist.

Comment: I see, I editted the answer such that `<%= yeoman.dist %>` is passed as an argument to the replace task from the `grunt.initConfig` section.

Comment: It still not working. Now the error: `Cannot read property 'key' of undefined `. Then I replaced the `this.data.key` to the string "dist". That error is hqndled, but the next is with the `mainRunner`: this is not defined.

Comment: I fixed the argument passing and writing to file. `key` is looked up in the `initConfig` section. Also see http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks

Comment: Ok, now it's did the replace, but only with the first row of the list.

Comment: I edited the answer to use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`, according to http://stringjs.com/#methods/replaceall-ss-newstr

Comment: Great, it's works well. Anyway I solved the problem in another way, but from this solution I learned a lot - thank you!